# Copying a Range and Calculating a Value

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently building a sheet that will organize data from designated cells into another designated cell. In some cases the cell being referenced to will be blank. Instead of having a blank cell or "#VALUE" showing in the compiled area, I'd like to have "N/A" show up instead. The code I have now works if there is a value in every cell being referenced to. But if one cell is empty (H12, E18, E17, E16, E15, etc) the code stops and an Error message appears as "Run Time error '13': Type mismatch".

```
   Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

   'See if quote full
    'if quote not full then add item
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A27:A102")) < 75 Then
     Dim fRow As Integer
    'search for first empty row on quote in specified range
    'and assign "fRow" to row number
    fRow = Range("A27:A102").Find(What:="", _
            After:=[A27], LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False).row
    'copy cell for cell
    Range("A" & fRow).Value = Range("B7") & "-" & Range("B10") & "-" & Range("E7") & "-" & Range("E8") & "-" & Range("E11")
    Range("B" & fRow).Value = Range("B14").Value 'Pipe Schedule
    Range("C" & fRow).Value = Range("B11").Value 'Gasket Size NPS
    Range("D" & fRow).Value = Range("H12").Value 'Sleeve Length [in]
    Range("E" & fRow).Value = Range("H12").Value * 25.4 'Sleeve Length [mm]
    Range("F" & fRow).Value = Range("H13").Value 'Sleeve Qty
    Range("G" & fRow).Value = Range("H11").Value 'Bolt Size
    Range("H" & fRow).Value = Range("H9").Value 'Isolating/BackUp Washer Qty
    'Range("I" & fRow).Value = Range("H9").Value 'Empty
    Range("J" & fRow).Value = Range("E19").Value 'Bolt Hole Qty
    Range("K" & fRow).Value = Range("E18").Value 'Bolt Hole Size [in]
    Range("L" & fRow).Value = Range("E18").Value * 25.4 'Bolt Hole Size [mm]
    Range("M" & fRow).Value = Range("E17").Value 'Bolt Hole Circle [in]
    Range("N" & fRow).Value = Range("E17").Value * 25.4 'Bolt Hole Circle [mm]
    Range("O" & fRow).Value = Range("E16").Value 'D Dim [in]
    Range("P" & fRow).Value = Range("E16").Value * 25.4 'D Dim [mm]
    Range("Q" & fRow).Value = Range("E15").Value 'C Dim [in]
    Range("R" & fRow).Value = Range("E15").Value * 25.4 'C Dim [mm]
    Range("S" & fRow).Value = Range("E13").Value 'B Dim [in]
    Range("T" & fRow).Value = Range("E13").Value * 25.4 'B Dim [mm]
    Range("U" & fRow).Value = Range("E14").Value 'A Dim [in]
    Range("V" & fRow).Value = Range("E14").Value * 25.4 'A Dim [mm]
    Range("W" & fRow).Value = Range("B11").Value 'Gasket Size NPS
Else ' if quote full give message
    MsgBox "Cart Full - Good Work!"
End If

End Sub
```

I know the error is because I'm trying to calculate a value from a blank cell, but how can I insert some type of "If" statement; or other logic, for the calculated values to return a number or "N/A" (if the reference cell is blank)?

Comment: IIf(condition, true_block, false_block) should help you (similar to the excel if-function):
`IIf(IsNull(Range(cell).value), "N/A", Range(cell.value))`

Comment: Thank you JanB. Sorry for the novice questions, but I'm still getting an Error. Doing more research, I'm thinking that this is designating an Empty or Blank Cell. But my understanding is that the "Null" function shouldn't care if the cell is blank or empty, correct? Below is the line that is giving me the error. I double checked and there is nothing showing in cell E18, but I'm not sure if its empty or blank?

Comment: Range("L" & fRow).Value = IIf(IsNull(Range("E18").Value), "N/A", Range("E18").Value * 25.4) 'Bolt Hole Size [mm]